# Does Google Chrome history stored have limits?

Tags: google-chrome

We viewed a webpage which had 40 links on each page. We clicked on 4 of the links. All on the same day at the same time. Now, today, we go back to the same page and 2 of the 4 links are blue and 2 are purple. Purple meaning Chrome is remembering that we viewed those 2 listings previously. Why do we not see all 4 in purple? It's as if Chrome remembers 2 of the 4 we viewed but not the other 2. Does Chrome have limits on how many links or files or data it stores in the history, etc. And the 2 that are in blue, even though we viewed those previously, is Chrome's way of emptying the history due to limits?

Comment: The page may be using CSS that overrides the default coloring of the links.

Comment: Cascading Style Sheets? That is all I see for CSS. Curious the ones not shown as having previously been viewed always at top of the page. As if to suggest that when first viewed each page was missing some entries. But the viewing was done very carefully. Today we began another search on same site and glanced at a few viewed the day before and never saw any listings that appeared as if we never looked at them. If Google Chrome does have some history limits, then how Chrome decides which links to no longer show colored is another question.

Comment: I assume Chrome is like most other browsers, using a time limit for remembering whether a link has been visited, not the number of links.

Comment: That is a good possibility but what we noticed was the ones that were not remembered were not among the very first looked at and in some chronological order.. We noticed 2-3 on the top of each page. Further examination and we clearly had viewed those not remembered.

Comment: Is it always just that one web page? Or do you see this issue on different sites?

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome shows the web pages that you've visited on Chrome in the last 90 days (source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589). If you want to bypass the limit, you should try *History Trends Unlimited*. Unlike Chrome, it saves your history locally and gives you some neat statistics.